# Sell On Quarters On The Dollar

Tags: prepositions, usage, idioms

I have a question about some possible error [here](http://sports.yahoo.com/blogs/nfl-shutdown-corner/what-s-next-for-wheeling--dealing-bears--trade-matt-forte--jay-cutler-172404441.html):

> New general manager Ryan Pace inherited a bloated, talent-deficient and aged roster, and he knew changes had to come. Pace is doing his best Theo Epstein impression here, shedding unwanted and ill-fitting pieces, even if he has ***to sell on quarters on the dollar***.

Is "*to sell* ***on*** *quarters on the dollar*" wrong?  Would "*to sell* ***for*** *quarters on the dollar*" be better?

Comment: Yes, it's a mistake.  The usual phrase is *selling **for** pennies on the dollar*, but quarters works just as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Googling that phrase "sell on quarters on the dollar", the *only* hits I get are for this question and for the article you quoted. (There are two pages of hits, but they are all the same article, quoted or repeated.)

The common phrase is "for pennies on the dollar" (at a great loss), but "*for* quarters on the dollar" is appearing as well, indicating either a nod to inflation or a lesser degree of loss:

> - Nov 6, 2007 - Your *quarters on the dollar* do still have value, pennies not so much, at least in my mind. - Investors Hub
> - Save up some cash for when they come calling. You can probably settle this for pennies on the dollar. Well, *quarters on the dollar* at least. - a redditor
> - I have found that it's more like *quarters on the dollar* in most cases. There is a huge inventory and many resources with which to find bank owned... - How to Buy Real Estate for Pennies on The Dollar
> - Often, teams trading the superstar will get three quarters on the dollar back, if they're lucky.

Etc.